# What does SVN mean in the "C++ support in Clang" page?

Tags: c++, clang

On the site [C++ Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), the column *Available in Clang?* has the value of `SVN` in many rows of the *C++2a implementation status* table. What does this mean? I tried to search Google with: `site:clang.llvm.org svn`, but couldn't find anything but few references to the Subversion version control system. Does this relate to that?

[image: Image of the page]

Comment: Clang's source used to be stored on SVN before they migrated everything to Git. My guess is that it's a weird way of saying it's available on their master, but not yet in a release?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel to be fair the [git migration isn't complete](https://llvm.org/GitHubMigrationStatus.html) so referring to stuff as being in SVN isn't too obscure

Comment: yes, "SVN" means the feature is complete in SVN but hasn't made it into a release yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the general consensus that "SVN" means that the feature is complete in Clang's SVN version control, but hasn't made it into a release just yet.